# Example of a Riemann integrable sequence of functions such that the the sequence of Riemann integrals diverges but... (see below)?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Is there a sequence $(f_n)$ of Riemann integrable functions such that $\lim f_n(x) = f(x)$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$ and $\lim\int_a^bf_n$ does not exists in Riemann sense, but it does in Lebesgue sense?

By the way the author said, is a simple example. But I waste a lot of time trying to find and nothing appear...

(please, apologize the bad english)

Comment: Can you state the problem exactly? It doesn't make sense (at least to me) as stated.

Comment: Okay. Let $(f_n)$ a sequence of Riemann integrable functions that converges almost everywhere on $[a,b]$. In general is not true that $\lim\int_a^bf_n = \int_a^b\lim f_n$. One thing that can happen is: the limit $\lim\int_a^bf_n$ may not exist.

What I want is a example. I can give one where $\lim\int_a^bf_n$ does not exist in both sense: Riemann and Lebesgue. But the author state this like one of the deficiencies of Riemann integral. This way, this problem not occur in the Lebesgue integral, or does not make sense to judge this aspect!

Comment: If it is not possible, why the author state this question as a deficiency of the Riemann Integral?

You can find it in the book Lebesgue Integration by Soo Bong Chae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $\ln_a^b f_n$ is simply a number; so if each number is defined but the sequence of numbers doesn't converge, then extending from Riemann integrals to Lebesgue integrals (which will all have the same value) doesn't change anything. If you want an example where $\int_a^b (\lim f_n)$ doesn't exist as a Riemann integral but does exist as a Lebesgue integral, then let $\{q_j\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $(a,b)$ and let $f_n(x) = 0$ except that $f_n(q_1)=\cdots=f_n(q_n)=1$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking about. But I am trying to understand why the author state this like a deficiency.

Can you give-me a simple example where the sequence of Riemann integrable functions $(f_n)$ converges almost everywhere on [a,b] but $\lim\int_a^b f_n$ doesn't exist? I found one, but it is not elegant.

Comment: I note that you didn't state in the question that the functions $f_n$ should converge pointwise; it would be easier to answer if you included this important detail. How about $a=0$, $b=1$, and $f_n(x) = 1/x$ when $x\ge 1/n$, $f(x)=0$ when $0<x<1/n$?

Comment: Its true, sorry.
The example that I found is very similar. The problem is that 1/x is not Lebesgue integrable...
Maybe I am daydreaming. I want to compare the Riemann Integral with Lebesgue Integral, and show that the last one is better. If I say: " if $f_1, f_2, ...$ are each Riemann integrable on [a, b] and $\lim f_n(x) = f(x)$ almost everywhere in $[a, b]$, then it is not in general true that $\lim\int_a^b f_n = \int_a^bf(x)$. One thing that can go wrong is the limit $\lim\int_a^b f_n$ may not exist ",
am I talking about a deficiency that Lebesgue integral overcome?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the Lebesgue integral overcomes this particular fact (I hesitate to call it a deficiency). Morally speaking, the Lebesgue integral allows more functions' integrals to be evaluated; this particular fact isn't held back by a non-evaluated integral.

Answer (score 0):

Take $(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Define a sequence $f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  as follows:

$f_n(x)=1$ if $x \in \{e_1,...,e_n \}$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise.

Each $f_n$ is continuous except at a finite number of points, hence riemann integrable. But the pointwise limit function is not riemann integrable, being the indicator function of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$.

NOTE THAT: This isn't what you wrote in your question, although I think this is what you intended. $\lim \int f_n$ is the limit of a sequence of number, by your own hypothesis on the $f_n$. This answer assumes (as I think it is the case) that you want a sequence of riemann integrable functions for which the pointwise limit is not riemann integrable.

Comment: Please, read my comment in the other answer.